# Why are Two Electric Range Burners Not Working?

Tags: appliances, range

My LG electric double oven range ([LDE3037ST](http://www.lg.com/us/cooking-appliances/lg-LDE3037ST-electric-range))

[image]

which is 3 years old made a popping sound accompanied by the smell of burnt electrical parts?/insulation?, and now the 2 right burners don't work. Is it the burner control board? Would a bad relay create a burnt insulation smell? What could the cause be?

UPDATE: Followed wallyk's advice. I traced the wires from the burners back to the PCB and found the fried relay. You can see the faint smoke mark on the black box in the lower right of the pic below. So, I'll have to replace the board. The insulation on the red wire on the right melted and split. If I cut the wire back to where the insulation is intact, can I re-use the wire? Or does that wire need to be replaced as well? Would it be unsafe to re-use the wire?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the controller, but it could also be a burner or a wire to a burner.

Have a look underneath the two right burners—with power shut off to the range.  I expect the cause will be readily apparent with a look.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I turned off the power and looked under the right 2 burners, but I didn't see anything unusual. I didn't see any fried components or wiring.

Comment: @Laxmidi:  Usually relays can be replaced as a component and are often not too hard to find a suitable replacement, not necessarily from the appliance manufacturer.  They might be soldered in, but they might also be in sockets for a minimal tool replacement.  Have a close look at them.   Yes, the wire can almost certainly be reused (unless it melted).  Cut off the damaged portion and replace the terminal.